# Proving $ \frac{1}{(\tan(x/2)+1)^2\cos^2(x/2)} = \frac{1}{1+\sin x}$

Tags: trigonometry

I have been stuck with this part of question and need help:

> Prove that: 
>   $$ \frac{1}{\left(\tan\frac{x}{2}+1\right)^2\cos^2\frac{x}{2}} = \frac{1}{1+\sin x}$$

Thank you!

Comment: Of course you can immediately take reciprocals of both sides. Do you know the half-angle formulas?

Comment: Yes, I tried using them but looks like it went the wrong way. Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$\frac{1}{(\tan\frac{x}{2}+1)^2\cos^2\frac{x}{2}} =\frac{1}{(\tan^2\frac{x}{2}+2\tan\frac{x}{2}+1)\cos^2\frac{x}{2}}$$
$$=\frac{1}{\sin^2\frac{x}{2}+2\sin\frac{x}{2}\cos\frac{x}{2}+\cos^2\frac{x}{2}}=\frac{1}{1+2\sin\frac{x}{2}\cos\frac{x}{2}}=\frac{1}{1+\sin x}$$

Answer (score 1):

Let $\tan\dfrac x2=t$

So we have
$$\dfrac{1+t^2}{(t+1)^2}=\cdots=\dfrac1{1+\dfrac{2t}{1+t^2}}$$

Now  [use](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tangent_half-angle_substitution#The_substitution)

Comment: (+) nice........